# How to pull an element from one webpage to display on another

Tags: html, css, xpath

I'm working on a website to display some details from another website. Specifically I have an element I wish to display. I can get the elements xpath or css path, and I'd like to use this to display the value of the element in HTML box on a unrelated website.

I'm rather new to this so my question is really this basic, I'm sure it's been asked before but I just don't know what search terms to use. I've looked up what I can but I'm unsure if what I have found can be used in a HTML box (I've tried and failed, but I'm unsure if that's an error on my part or the application of the wrong method).

```
XPath: //*[@id="box2-server-status"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/img
```

CSS Path:

```
#box2-server-status > div.box2-content > div:nth-child(4) > div.server-status-indicator > img
```

Any help/link with guides welcome!

Comment: I think that you will need server-side technology such as PHP.

Comment: You can do this using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_html_scraper)

Comment: hi @FraserOfSmeg did you take a look at my example that I sent you,, is that functionality that you look for or?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, if that is what can be of help to you..

I got this page..

https://mkdizajn.github.io/my-colors/

and I'm about to pull the title from this page:

http://mkdizajn.github.io/about/

If you open inspector on that page and enter this code in 'console' (of if I got time and add it there in the source ;)

```
var content; 
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://mkdizajn.github.io/about/', 
    success: function(data){ 
         content = data;
         var body = jQuery( content ) ;
         alert( body.find('h1').text() ) ;
    } 
})
```

you will have to get content from second page in the form of alert.. .. take a note that page is from that same domain, that is very important

https://mkdizajn.github.io/my-colors/

hth, k