# How to display content from the current page on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a webpage where a dynamic table is generated when the user specifies certain things. I want to display the results in a different format (in a report style) without running the queries again (to maintain consistent results).

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292653/how-to-pull-an-element-from-one-webpage-to-display-on-another) and related ones, but they pull content from a page, where as what I want is to **push** the content to a new page.

Basically what I want is to display `#my-table` on a new tab when the `button` is clicked.
[image]

Comment: What about storing the data in json format and store the json in localstorage.

Comment: I didn't know about it and I just read about it, I think that is the solution to my problem, thanks. Maybe add as a solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). later on, you can access same data on another page.